# Python Plotly Line Chart not displaying Lines for multiple Years

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a WebApp that would display some charts based on data downloaded from an Oracle DB.

I have a separate Python file where I connect to the server=>download the data into Pandas dataframe=>save the data as Parquet file.
Then in a separate Python file where I am creating a Dash app. I import the Parquet file saved by the first file, connect some callbacks and display the line chart.

Data

- contains about 50k rows
- is monthly (Jan-Dec) product data for last 3 years of the business
- looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZviVs.png)

This code is the graph part of my WebApp

```
    @app.callback(
        Output('our_graph','figure'),
        [Input('product','value'),
         Input('type','value'),
         Input('category','value')])
    def build_graph(first, second, third):
        dff=df[(df['product']==first)&
               (df['type']==second)&
               (df['category']==third)]
        fig = px.line(dff, x="month", y="sum", color="year",height=600)
        fig.update_layout(
                        xaxis=dict(tickmode='linear'),
                        yaxis={'title':'Amount'},
                        title={'text':'Product Analysis',
                               'font':{'size':28},'x':0.5,'xanchor':'center'})
        return fig
```

I am basically trying to filter data by a product/category/type and then see how they were doing over last 3 years. Each line on the chart should represent a year (2021, 2022, 2023).

What I am expecting to get is something like this (made in excel): https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpWxV.png

But what I am getting is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnbHu.png)

I have been trying to figure out what the problem but can't find any solution. Lines are overlapping and chart is useless.

I'd appreciate any recommendations and help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by simply adding the following line:

```
dff=dff.groupby(["year","month","product","type","category"])["sum"].sum().reset_index()
```

Basically data needed to be "squeezed" and grouped/aggregated first and only then passed down to Plotly to visualize it.